# Partition Hard disk with start sector 1

Tags: linux, partitioning, nas, fdisk, sectors

I have a new Hard Disk which I want to use for NAS drive. The requirement is that the partition as seen in fdisk should be as below.

```
Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          37      297171   83  Linux
```

Normally I am able to partition but start sector comes as either 1024 or 63. I want it to start at 1. The HDD is 2TB.

Answer (score 3):

You can't because of the reserved sectors for the [bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) allocation. In normal situations, there's no practical reason to do this anyway.

Comment: I want to add bootloader of the NAS on it.

Comment: Then use whatever tool the OS of your NAS provides.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure, the 1 / 37 geometry is meant to be cylinders (in the old CHS-speak), not blocks: STarting block 1, Ending block 37 might not easily result in 297171 blocks ...

Switch to blocks as display unit on the original disk, I am quite positive, it will show up as 63